# Can I remove this door sill?

Tags: doors, patio, threshold

I have Amtico flooring booked in to replace the existing vinyl and I’m wondering if this sill can be removed to create more space or is it part of the structure/ support for the patio doors? Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I know somebody with the same house style (new build) who doesn’t have this big wooden sill, the flooring just goes right up to the door, so I’m a little confused.[image]

Comment: Is there clear space underneath all the way to the exterior wall? Is there some wood block obscuring the exterior wall? Is there any concrete obscuring the exterior wall. Judging by the near edge at your picture's right, it looks clear under there, but if there's nothing under it, then I would expect it to noticeably deflect when stepped upon.

Comment: What does the outside base of the wall look like? Is the interior slab elevation very close to the exterior slab elevation?

Comment: If I was to put my hand underneath, there isn't a space going all the way to the back/ exterior wall which is why I was nervous about trying to take it out. It has been stepped on quite a lot when using the doors and the sealant has come away where it meets the UPVC frames l, so there’s definitely flexibility in it. I’ve added an image of the exterior.

Comment: If there's broom finished concrete outside the wall and the concrete workers placed everything at once, then they could have accidentally broomed the concrete a little in the house, where they've buried it with that sill. If there's an elevation change, then maybe they missed the correct line with that and buried the mistake. It's one of those things where who knows what you'll find in there? Maybe it's full of gold bars. Or Jimmy Hoffa. You could dismantle things to look nondestructively, but it's probably easier to cut it flush with the wall anticipating the possibility of replacement.

Comment: If you just go nuts and tear it apart, then the part that comes out from under the doors could be difficult to fix. Or does it stop at the edge of the door?

Comment: Can I *permanently* remove this door sill? Depends on what's going on there when you take one up and have a look, and then take them all up so that one of them isn't hiding Mr. Hoffa. It's a Catch 22. That it's at grade level is concerning.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose all we can do is take one up as cleanly as possible and see what’s lurking underneath! Just baffles me how our neighbours have exactly the same house and patio door setup yet they have no sill. I’ve read that it’s possible it was added due to the level between door threshold and floor being too big of a gap to pass building regs, hence adding the ‘window sill’ to create the step up so it passes the new build CML inspection. Seems likely with new builds these days just being thrown up. Thanks for the knowledge and fingers crossed there’s nobody hiding!